# Discriminant unions in typescript with switch giving error in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a reducer function

```
function reducer(state: AuthState, action: Action): AuthState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        user: action.payload.user,
        access_token: action.payload.access_token,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        ...initialState,
        user: { id: "", name: "", email: "" },
        access_token: null,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Type Definition of discriminant union type

```
export type Action =
  | {
      type: string;
      payload: AuthState;
    }
  | { type: string };
```

gives error   property action.payload not found in Action type

Comment: But that's not a discriminated union, you need a discriminant.

Comment: typo I am correcting it

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a more specific type than `string` in your action so discrimination will actually work.

Something like this

```
export type Action =
  | {
      type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
      payload: AuthState;
    }
  | { type: 'LOGOUT' };
```